# Visual Studio casting issue

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, casting, unsigned, signed

I'm trying to do, what I imagined to be, a fairly basic task. I have two unsigned char variables and I'm trying to combine them into a single signed int. The problem here is that the unsigned chars start as signed chars, so I have to cast them to unsigned first.

I've done this task in three IDE's; MPLAB (as this is an embedded application), MATLAB, and now trying to do it in visual studio. Visual is the only one having problems with the casting.

For an example, two signed chars are -5 and 94. In MPLAB I first cast the two chars into unsigned chars:

```
unsigned char a = (unsigned char)-5;
unsigned char b = (unsigned char)94;
```

This gives me 251 and 94 respectively. I then want to do some bitshifting and concat:

```
int c = (int)((((unsigned int) a) << 8) | (unsigned int) b);
```

In MPLAB and MATLAB this gives me the right *signed* value of -1186. However, the exact same code in visual refuses to output results as a signed value, only unsigned (64350). This has been checked by both debugging and stepping through the code and printing the results:

```
printf("%d\n", c);
```

What am I doing wrong? This is driving me insane. The application is an electronic device that collects sensor data, then stores it on an SD card for later decoding using a program written in C. I technically *could* do all the calculations in MPLAB and then store those on the SDCARD, but I refuse to let Microsoft win.

I understand my method of casting is very unoptimised and you could probably do it in one line, but having had this problem for a couple of days now I've tried to break the steps down as much as possible.

Any help is most appreciated!

Comment: I just tested this in `gcc` and it produces `64350`, so it is hardly a Microsoft problem. I believe it is correct behavior for the C programming language.

Comment: If you're putting two 8 bit values in the lower 16 bits of a 32 bit type, why does the sign (in the upper 16 bits) matter? If you mask and shift the 8 bit values back out, you'll get the correct results.

Comment: @Dan, I think he wants his variable to be interpreted as a signed `16-bit` integer directly, rather than just wanting to pack the two `8-bit` quantities and then extracting them out again later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that an `int` on most systems is 32-bits. If you concatenate two 8-bit quantities and store it into a 32-bit quantity, you will get a positive integer because you are not setting the `sign` bit, which is the most significant bit. More specifically, you are only populating the lower 16 bits of a 32-bit integer, which will naturally be interpreted as a positive number.

You can fix this by explicitly using as 16-bit signed int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char a = (unsigned char)-5;
    unsigned char b = (unsigned char)94;
    int16_t c = (int16_t)((((unsigned int) a) << 8) | (unsigned int) b);
    printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

Note that I am on a Linux system, so you will probably have to change `stdint.h` to the Microsoft equivalent, and possibly change `int16_t` to whatever Microsoft calls their `16-bit` signed integer type, if it is different, but this should work with those modifications.

Comment: This seems to be it! Thank you very much. I, for some reason, assumed Visual would conform to the same int system as my embedded C code, which is using a 16-bit microcontroller/compiler. As MPLAB uses a 16-bit system and MATLAB automatically selects variable sizes this would explain why they both worked and Visual didn't.

Comment: In my case, as I'm on a 64-bit OS, would that mean my ints were even larger at 64-bit as opposed to 32-bit? Does Visual (and other IDEs) follow the OS bit size for their ints or do they generally all have their ints at 32-bit?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct behavior of the standard C language. When you convert an `unsigned` to a signed type, the language does not perform sign extension, i.e. it does not propagate the highest bit of the unsigned into the sign bit of the signed type.

You can fix your problem by casting `a` to a signed `char`, like this:

```
unsigned char a = (unsigned char)-5;
unsigned char b = (unsigned char)94;
int c = (signed char)a << 8 | b;
printf("%d\n", c); // Prints -1186
```

Now that `a` is treated as signed, the language propagates its top bit into the sign bit of the 32-bit `int`, making the result negative.

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/aThfTY)

Answer (score 1):

Converting an out-of-range unsigned value to a signed value causes *implementation-defined behaviour*, which means that the compiler must document what it does in this situation; and different compilers can do different things.

In C99 there is also a provision that the compiler may raise a signal in this case (terminating the program if you don't have a signal handler).  I believe it was undefined behaviour in C89, but C99 tightened this up a bit.

Is there some reason you can't go:

```
signed char x = -5;
signed char y = 94;
int c = x * 256 + y;
```

?

BTW if you are OK with implementation-defined behaviour, and your system has a 16-bit type then you can just go,  with `#include <stdint.h>`,

```
int c = (int16_t)(x * 256 + y);
```

To explain, C deals in values. In math, `251 * 256 + 94` is a positive number, and C is no exception to that. The bit-shift operators are just `*2` and `/2` in disguise. If you want your value to be reduced `(mod 65536)` you have to specifically request that.

If you also think in terms of values rather than representations, you don't have to worry about things like sign bits and sign extension.